# El texto de mi Label se queda centrado usando Tkinter en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito crear una ventana donde quede el texto recargado a la derecha pero todo se queda centrado. Uso "justify" y "anchor" y no cambia la posición del texto y cuando agrego "side" todo el texto se sale de de la ventana. Estoy usando .pack() porque no sé cómo crear una ventana que cuente con una scrollbar usando .grid().

Comment: ¡Hola! Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber cómo funcionamos y también pasarte por [como realizar una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para aprender a realizar preguntas magistrales. Con la pregunta tal cual la has formulado es difícil ayudarte (tal vez no difícil, pero poco práctico). Te recomiendo leer las formas pasa posicionar widgets [aquí](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/tkinter.html#the-packer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

ventana.geometry("400x400")

texto = tk.Label(ventana, text="texto a la derecha",bg="red")
texto.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Asi funciona pero si tienes más widgets en tu ventana, pack los acomodara automaticamente, te recomiendo mejor que uses grid()

Un ejemplo basico de scrollbar:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

ventana.geometry("400x400")

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(ventana)
scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nwes")

listbox = tk.Listbox(ventana,height=5,yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
listbox.insert(tk.END,*lista)
listbox.grid(row=0,column=0)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan Carlos. Llevaba tiempo buscando una forma de crear mi ventana con una scrollbar usando grid() para que fuera más fácil trabajar con el resto de widgets. Me resultó muy útil el código que me brindaste para lo que tenía planeado.